# Resources for Chinese in formal situations

Tags: mandarin, resources, formal

I am looking for a comprehensive guide of formal Chinese for business emails, memos, laws, newspapers, etc. I am aware that some sentence patterns are only used in a formal context. For example, ....均.. is used in a formal sense to mean "entire," but is rarely used in casual Chinese. I am also aware of the complex honorifics involved with business meetings such as 貴公司 etc. However, I can't seem to find any books that dive deep into the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possibly a duplicate of https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23303/books-websites-for-learning-chinese-business-letters?rq=1 ]

Here there a lot of resources you can look: [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese?rq=1)

In particular, for business they recommend:

- [Business Chinese Learning Facebook Group](https://www.facebook.com/businesschineselearning) There are a lot of posts about business Chinese vocabulary, job interview phrase, Chinese business culture and etiquette.
- 新思路 (Business Chinese) series textbook

Moreover, searching online I came across the following books you could check:

- Advanced Chinese through Business Topics, Listening and Oral Expression: Discussing Everything Chinese, Part 3 by Dr. Lili Teng Foti, Rongzhen Li, Dr. Jie Liu, Dr. Wen-Hua Du
- Here they also provide more recommendations: [Recommended Business Chinese Textbooks For Different Levels from digmandarin.com](https://www.digmandarin.com/recommended-business-chinese-textbooks-for-different-levels.html)

Finally, I imagine working on improving your level of Chinese in general could also help you in formal situations.